# using php via terminal not loading

Tags: php, terminal

I'm trying to use php via the command line. I've setup my alias to the MAMP php5.4.10 version.

It's giving me the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
  Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 15.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm at a loss; i've tried looking for a newer version to update it to, but can't find it.

Comment: Read that you could solve this problem by commenting out the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars`, haven't tried it though.

Comment: You could also try checking if you have any other libfreetype libraries installed in your system by executing `locate libfreetype.6.dylib` from your terminal. If you find another version you could then try to copy it into your `/Applications/MAMP/Library` folder, replacing the older version.

Comment: I've tried replacing the version from elsewhere on the machine, and even from my macbook that has no problems, but they all appear to be the same version. Commenting out the line doesn't actually make any difference to the error, even after restarting Terminal :/